# Use Shared Preferences inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I want to use shared preferences inside a fragment. One to check if that fragment is run for the first time and if yes then it stores another value into shared preference. I don't know why it just doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
String user_name;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_fragment, container, false);

    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    if(sp.getBoolean("isFirst",true)) {
        edit.putBoolean("isFirst", false);
        edit.putString("First_Name", FirstRunActivity.username).apply();
    }

    user_name = sp.getString("First_Name","NOT WORKKING");

    TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);

    test.setText(user_name);


    }
```

Comment: If the `sp.getBoolean("isFirst",true)` returns false (if it is already set false), the if condition won't execute and you are not setting the `First_Name` to `SharedPreferences`. Check whether you already have `false` for `isFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sp.getBoolean("isFirst",true)) { 
   edit.putBoolean("isFirst", false); 
   edit.putString("First_Name", FirstRunActivity.username).commit(); 
}
```

Comment: Hello, Do you mean to say I should commit() instead of apply(). If yes then it is not working still and the difference in both of them is that apply() works in background, and commit() works immediately. Right?

Comment: Ok.. What do u mean by code doesn't work? Getting any error? Or getting "Not working" as value?

Comment: When I run the app the "test" TextView shows my name(that it should). When I press the back button the app closes. When I restart it. It again shows my name. But, if I close it from the Overview button. It destroys and on restarting it shows "NOT WORKKING". SInce it worked in the previous case that means it stored the value of FirstRunActivity.username. Right? But my problem specifically is that why doesn't it shows in the last case

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't understand that. Can you please comment in easier terms. :)

Comment: Yes. It sets value in user_name as "NOT WORKING". As if "First_Name" is lost.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, if you did not set the value of isFirst to true initially then it will always return false

```
if(sp.getBoolean("isFirst",true)) {
    edit.putBoolean("isFirst", false);
    edit.putString("First_Name", FirstRunActivity.username).apply();
}
```

**You can try this solution.**

First in your FirstRunActivity, you can set a class member boolean variable

```
private boolean inFirstActivity = true;
```

then in your onCreate method, you need to set your SharePreference isFirst key value like

```
if(inFirstActivity) edit.putBoolean('isFirst', true);
```

then, you can check with the code thereafter in the class.

```
if(sp.getBoolean("isFirst",true)) {
  edit.putBoolean("isFirst", false);
  edit.putString("First_Name", FirstRunActivity.username).apply();
}
```

Comment: But "isFirst" is not a variable it is just that TAG string to look for (in sharedPreferences sp) and when that fragment would for the first time then "isFirst" would not be there therefore it must return true. Right? Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, it is a key but need to assign a value to the key expect it will return false since it is a boolean.